# Coldfusion 9 installation problem with IIS7

Tags: coldfusion, installation

Windows web server 2008 R2 64 bit, CF9 64 bit, IIS7, ISAPI extensions and filters and II6 metabase compatability installed. OS is on C default, and trying to install CF to D:

Testing IIS and it shows index.html correctly from c:\inetpub\wwwroot at http://localhost/index.html

Then I install CF to D:\ , single standard server licence, select run with all IIS sites, select C:\inetpub\wwwroot as the web root for administrator, and when it gets to the bit where it is supposed to open up administrator to complete the installation it opens up the browser with a 500 error.

Now when I go back to http://localhost/index.html I also get a 500 error, if i uninstall CF I can again reach the html page.

CFIDE has been installed in C:\inetpub\wwwroot presumably correctly. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Update

The exact IIS error is

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Module  IsapiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler AboMapperCustom-28262
Error Code  0x800700c1
Requested URL   http://127.0.0.1:80/test.htm
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.htm
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

Resolves as below

Comment: Try getting the 9.0.1 update and install that after installing 9. That has better support for IIS 7.

Comment: I want to install 8 first, because I had web service issues on a recent hot fix, which I know were not there on 9 (or in fact on 9.01 update), and I want to pin down the issue or eliminate. Is it even possible to apply the 9.01 update before finishing the initial install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm humiliated to admit it, but the problem was that what I thought was the cf9 64 bit installer, was the 32 bit one.

@ Dave and @ CfSimplicity many thanks for your help and in particular the IIS user account stuff was new learning for me.

Answer (score 6):

There is a setting *Enable 32-Bit Applications* under Application Pool>Advanced settings.  Set this to True and you will gain access to your CFIDE>Administrator page.

Comment: Can confirm this is the fix for a clean CF2016 install on W2K8R2 with IIS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first trying a restart.  It is one of those things that after the fact sounds so obvious, but you never think of it.  I know I have had problems with installing CF under IIS and had to restart the server to get it running.

Comment: No luck with restart  i'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the file system permissions for this folder:

D:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig

The account that IIS uses needs Read, Execute and Modify permissions on this folder and below.

Comment: I installed IIS as administrator. How do I know what account IIS uses? Administrator, and System have read , execute and modify permissions for that folder.

Comment: To check the IIS user account, in the IIS Manager (GUI) go to Application Pools, then "Set Application Pool Defaults". Under Process Model look for the "Identity".

Comment: Actually this may depend on your settings under the "Home" (root) IIS settings. Look in Authentication to see what the user for Anonymous Authentication is. We use the Application Pool identity, but you may have another user account set.

Comment: IIS user account is set as ApplicationPoolIdentity, and the permissions on wsconfig are given to administrators, creator owner, system and users

Comment: OK, if you look up the AppPool Identity as above (in AppPool defaults), then try giving that specific user Read, Execute and Modify permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of two problems.

1) you haven't installed CGI, ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters aren't installed yet in Web Server (IIS) of Server manager.

[Window 2008 R2 with Coldfusion](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2010/12/15/404-status-code-in-Window-2008-R2-with-Coldfusion)

2) you need to enable 32 bit application at IIS7.

[Internal 500 error CF9 on Window 2008](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2010/9/9/internal-500-error-cf9-on-window-2008)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach with my Windows 7 Home Premium - See http://coldfusioner.blogspot.com/2011/12/fix-number-1-installing-64-bit.html

It seems that I was successful by using the IIS Connector batch scripts manually and then to create a second default web site after installing the handlers. My article link above shows the steps I took - a very raw article and will likely be refined as I hear from others how they adapted my approach. The important thing is that this worked ;>) I hope it helps others...

Comment: Including an external reference to a well documented source is appreciated here on Stack Overflow but it is important to include in your answer the most important/relevant snippets from the external source and give context as to how to answer the question because if that link goes dead (server goes down, etc), then your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Great comment since the link is now dead... :`(

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your Application Pool that is part of your default website. It is possible to set it to run 32 bit applications. Try setting the Enable32bit to false in the defaultapppool of your IIS server, restart the app pool and your www service itself. Then try to use the ColdFusion wsconfig tool to add the IIS mapping. It should work even without the cf 9 updater 1 being installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

​To avoid a 500 error when accessing the Administration console for the first time when installaing ColdFusion 9 on a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.5 installed, include the "IIS_IUSRS" user group with "Full Control" to the \Lib\wsconfig folder in Enterprise server or \runtime\lib\wsconfig folder in Standard server. Before starting the ColdFusion install, make sure the "IIS 6 Management Compatibility" functions are installed, especially the "IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility" function.

Assuming that you use the default installation paths (C:\JRun4 for Enterprise or C:\ColdFusion9 for Standard), here is a step-by-step approach:

Begin the ColdFusion installer as an Administrator. At the completion of the initial installation process, but before accessing the online Administration console, do the following:

1.) At the Start Menu, select "Computer"

2.) In the Enterprise install, go to C:\JRun4\lib. For the Standard install, go to C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib.

3.) Right-click "wsconfig" and select "Properties" to open the wsconfig properties dialog box.

4.) Click the "Security" tab.

5.) Click "Edit" to change permissions for that folder.

6.) Click "Add..." to add a new user/group.

7.) Enter "IIS_IUSRS" in the Object name field and click OK to return to the Permissions dialog box.

8.) In the permissions dialog box, ensure that the "IIS_IUSRS" group is highlighted and click "Full Control" in the "Allow" column, then click "OK" to close the dialog box. Ensure that the permissions change will affect all files and folders under wsconfig.

9.) Click "OK" to close the wsconfig properties box.

Return to the ColdFusion installer wizard and continue the installation by clicking the open ColdFusion Administrator link. If the settings are correct, after a minute or two, a web browser with the ColdFusion Administrator Console should appear so you can complete the installation.